# Fazer select personalizado no DJANGO

Tags: python-3.x, django

**model.py**

```
class Produto(models.Model):

    nome=models.CharField('nome', max_length=100)

    marca=models.CharField('nome', max_length=100)

    categ=models.ForeignKey(Produto, verbose_name='Produto')


class Categ(models.Model):

    categ_desc=models.CharField('categ', max_length=100)
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para um *select*, conforme abaixo, e converter em JSON o resultado:

```
select a.nome,a.marca,b.categ_desc from Produto a inner join Categ b on a.id=b.id
```

Estou fazendo assim, mas não traz a descrição da tabela `categ`.

```
Produto.objects.select_related()
```

Comment: Está certo a parte `a.id = b.id`? Não seria `a.categ = b.id`?

Comment: Sim escrevi errado. Mas eu preciso com Django exibir as informações das 2 tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

### Simples assim:

```
class Categ(models.Model):
    categ_desc=models.CharField('categ', max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.categ_desc

class Produto(models.Model):
    nome=models.CharField('nome', max_length=100)
    marca=models.CharField('marca', max_length=100) 
    categ=models.ForeignKey(Produto, verbose_name='Produto')

produtos = Produto.objects.all()
```

Se voce executar o comando `print produtos[0]` voce obterá o primeiro registro da tabela Produto, com todas as informações, inclusive do campo relacionado, nesse caso `categ`, note que se voce não definir a função `__str__` o campo categ virá como um objeto. Uma boa prática é definir `__str__` para todas as suas classes Model.

**Obs.:**
Mudei o nome do campo marca, pois estava duplicado com o nome do produto.